# Unable to get max value using annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

here is the models.py

```
class StoreProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product')
    category = models.ForeignKey('products.Category')
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store')
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

    objects = StoreProductManager()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

here is the views.py

```
if discount:
                max_discount = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=item).values_list('discount' , flat=True).annotate(Max('discount'))
                min_price_store = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=item , discount=max_discount).values_list('store__StoreName' , flat=True)

                print max_discount, min_price_store

                if discount > max_discount:
                    item.discount = discount
                    item.save()
```

the annotate query returns result like this

```
[30L, 20L, 40L]
```

What i want here is that it should return the maximum discount..but it is throwing multiple results like 20L , 30L , 40L .

what can i do to get the max value for discount ?

Thank You.

Comment: The issue with your query is that you're currently trying to group by `discount` field and then finding the `Max()` of each group, that is basically returning the distinct discounts to you. The correct way is to use `aggregate()`.

Comment: @Aditya Did you get an answer regarding this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/37550364/4099593? You can ask in a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python But I dunno if you can speak there as of now.

Comment: No i didnt get it and plus i was getting negative reviews so i deleted it@BhargavRao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `aggregate` as `annotate` only adds objects to your query

```
  storeproduct = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=item).aggregate(max_discount=Max('discount'))
```

`storeproduct['max_discount']` will return the maximum discount value and can be used in your next query like so:

```
 min_price_store = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=item , discount=storeproduct['max_discount']).values_list('store__StoreName' , flat=True)
```

Comment: the second query returns more than one result...it should return the store with maximum discount

Comment: What if there is more than one store with the maximum discount value?

Comment: it displays like this {'max_discount': 40} ....how do i get the value out of i t?

Comment: what can we do in that case? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Like I've posted: `storeproduct['max_discount']`. Depends on what you are trying to achieve. You could return the store with *oldest establishment date*, but this is only a suggestion. The choice is up to you